# /proc/pid/stack backtrace size in linux

Tags: linux

I'm trying to look at the backtrace of a running process, but /proc/pid/stack only has 5 calls, and not the full backtrace.  Is it possible to configure this to report more frames?

Comment: Just to make sure there is no missunderstanding: `/proc/[pid]/stack` is supposed to trace the kernel stack **not** user stack (try to attach with gdb to see this) so usually it shouldn't be too deep. Are you sure you are missing frames?

Comment: Ah, I see.  That would explain it - I thought it was user stack as well.